# Zendesk Nodejs API attachments using node-zendesk

Tags: node.js, api, upload, zendesk

I have a Nodejs app and I'm using **"node-zendesk"** NPM package for using Zendesk API. The official Zendesk NPM package **"zendesk-node-api"** is not useful and because of that i'm using **"node-zendesk"**.
My problem is when I want to create ticket with API inclouding attachments.

This is the example of that:

```
client.attachments.upload(file, { filepath: 'dog.jpg' }, function () {
  // if no error  
  client.tickets.create(ticket, function () {
     res.status(200).end();
  }
}
```

My question is:

- I need an example of "file" object. What should be inside that?
- And for "filepath", Should I put the image full filepath on my server starting by 'http....' ? Should I use Multer? Could you please give me a clear example?

Comment: have you tried the example provided in the library here - https://github.com/blakmatrix/node-zendesk/blob/master/examples/upload-attachment.js#L13-L24

Answer (score 1):

have you tried the example provided in the library here - https://github.com/blakmatrix/node-zendesk/blob/master/examples/upload-attachment.js#L13-L24

```
client.attachments.upload(path.resolve(
  './examples/busey.gif'),
  {
    filename: 'busey.gif'
  },
  function (err, req, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2, true));
});
```

'filepath' looks like it's relative to the file or absolute file path, up to you.  can start with file:// or whatever your local environment requires.  Probably not https because that's accessing across the web and not locally.

Comment: You mean I have to upload that to my server and use "http://mysite/image.png" or not? if not what exactly? from my PC (not possible) ?

Comment: @SamiAlMorshedi - where is the image stored?  If I'm not wrong, you'd want to store it in a place that the script can access.